# Multiply pandas dataframe as mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes like the following:

**occurrences**

```
doc    0    1    2    ...    1809(=n)
  0    0    0    1    ...       1
  1    0    0    1    ...       0
  2    0    0    1    ...       0
  ..  ..    ..   ..   ...       .
  m   ......................... 0
```

**dictionary**

```
id    term
 0     foo
 1     bar
 2     lorem
 ..    ..
 n     ipsum
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve, for each row of 'occurrences', the terms (through the id, that is the column header in the first dataframe) that has '1' as cell value.
In my example, considering the first row of occurrences, I would have: ['lorem','ipsum']

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts I got it working in this way (maybe not so cool..)

```
def get_vocabulary(occurences, dictionary):
    for index, row in dtm_.iterrows():
        # iterate on each row == each document
        doc = row.values.tolist() # convert row to list
        ngrams = []
        for i in range(len(doc)): # for each element
            if doc[i] != 0: 
                ngrams.append(dictionary.iloc[i, 1]) # match from vocabulary the term with positional index
    return ngrams
```

The final output is:

```
['scheduling', 'distributed', 'deadline', .... , 'rate monotonic scheduling algorithm']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with `np.where`

```
occurrences = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0]])
dictionary=pd.DataFrame({'term':['foo','bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum']})

idx = np.where(occurrences)
(pd.Series(dictionary.values[idx[1]].ravel())
   .groupby(idx[0]).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
0    [lorem, ipsum]
1      [bar, ipsum]
2      [foo, lorem]
dtype: object
```